# Error double click the file "*.R" after updating R and Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Normally, after I coded/programmed to complete my project in R, I will press "command + S" to store those code lines to the folder in current working direction, file "* .R". Then, If I want to review the code lines, I just go to those folder and double-click the file "*.R", the code lines will present in RStudio.

Today, I have just updated R and RStudio, I do the same but the code lines will only appear in R environment instead of RStudio.

What's going on with my R? Please help me!

> R version 4.0.0
>
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
>
> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
>
> RStudio Version 1.3.959

Comment: You need to select the default app for opening .R files as RStudio. Your mac has default as R.

Comment: @Singh OMG, the solution is so easy. Please press "Answer Your Question" and answer  again, and I can mark it as a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the default app for opening .R files as RStudio. Your mac has default app as R.